# issues in creating Writable characteristic in Core Bluetooth Framework

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am new to Core Bluetooth Framework. I am developing an application that act as peripheral. I need the app to notify characteristic value to subscribed centrals and also write the value of characteristic by the connected central. I am setting the value of characteristic while creating it. The issue is when i am setting the property of characteristic to notify or write it is showing error "Characteristics with cached values must be read-only". Can anybody help me ?

```
 var charValue = characteristicDetail["value"] as String
 var charProperties:CBCharacteristicProperties = getProperty(characteristicDetail["properties"] as String )
 let data = charValue.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
 var characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: charId, properties: charProperties, value: data, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.Readable)



func getProperty(string:String) -> CBCharacteristicProperties
    {
    var propertyString:CBCharacteristicProperties?
    switch string{
    case "r","R":
        propertyString = CBCharacteristicProperties.Read
    case "w","W":
        propertyString = CBCharacteristicProperties.Write
    case "n","N":
        propertyString = CBCharacteristicProperties.Notify
    case "i","I":
        propertyString = CBCharacteristicProperties.Indicate
    case "rw","wr","WR","RW":
        propertyString = CBCharacteristicProperties.Read|CBCharacteristicProperties.Write
    case "rn","nr","NR","RN":
        propertyString = CBCharacteristicProperties.Read|CBCharacteristicProperties.Notify
    case "wn","nw","NW","WN":
        propertyString = CBCharacteristicProperties.Write|CBCharacteristicProperties.Notify
    default:
        propertyString = CBCharacteristicProperties.Read
    }
    return propertyString!

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you specify a non-nil `value` when you create the `CBMutableCharacteristic` then it is a 'cached characteristic' and as the error message says, you cannot change the value later.

From the documentation of the `CBMutableCharacteristic` `init` method -

> *value* - The characteristic value to be cached. If nil, the value is dynamic and will be requested on demand.

Specify `nil` when you create the `CBMutableCharacteristic`-  You supply the value when requested in the `didReceiveReadRequest` `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` method.

If you have centrals that have subscribed to the characteristic then you should also call `updateValue` on your `CBPeripheralManager` whenever the value changes.

Be sure to read the section *Performing Common Peripheral Role Tasks* in the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH4-SW1)

Answer (score -1):

I found a solid post Medium that contains tons of great snippets for different tasks when it comes to BLE:

Create a service:

```
let serviceUUID = CBUUID(string: kServiceUUID)
let service = CBMutableService(type: serviceUUID, primary: true)
```

Create characteristics:

```
let characteristicUUID = CBUUID(string: kCharacteristicUUID)
let properties: CBCharacteristicProperties = [.Notify, .Read, .Write]
let permissions: CBAttributePermissions = [.Readable, .Writeable]
let characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(
    type: characteristicUUID,
    properties: properties,
    value: nil,
    permissions: permissions)
```

Add characteristics to a service:

```
service.characteristics = [characteristic1, characteristic2]
```

Add a service to the peripheral manager:

```
peripheralManager.addService(service)
```

[Source](https://medium.com/@shu223/core-bluetooth-snippets-with-swift-9be8524600b2#.kjxu4c30i)